# Oracle PL/SQL - SELECT grouped IDs from a subset of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `HeldItems` in Oracle 11g:

```
Carrier      Item
1            A
1            B
1            C
2            B
2            C
3            E
4            A
4            B
4            C
4            D
4            E
```

Say I want the `Carrier`s that have the `Item` subset A, B, and C to this effect:

```
Carrier
1
4
```

I'm trying to get them by:

```
SELECT Carrier
FROM HeldItems
WHERE Item IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY Carrier
```

But that will obviously give me `Carrier`s like 2 and I can't just

```
GROUP BY Carrier HAVING Item IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

What conditions do I need to use to obtain the IDs that comply with only a subset of items (A, B, C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is close.  You can count the number of distinct items in the `HAVING` clause and verify that there are 3 distinct items.

```
SELECT Carrier
FROM HeldItems
WHERE Item IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY Carrier
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Item) = 3
```

This will return all carriers having the subset of items A, B, and C, and possibly other items as well.  If you also wanted to find carriers only having these three items, the above query could be modified.